# What is in LibreOffice Calc the equivalent to Excel's "Paste Special > Value"?

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

In my professional life, I'm limited to use Microsoft Office. In Excel there is an option ows to render the result of a formula to be pasted as a "fixed value".

For instance `A1 = "I"`,`B1 = "ride"`, `C1 = "a"` and `D1 = "bike"`
In E1, I can place a formula to concatenate the values of A1 through D1 to display the sentence "I ride a bike", but if I should copy and paste that cell, I would just get the formula again, both if I write the formula with relative positioning, and if the values in A1:D1 change.
To solve this problem, Excel has "Paste Special > Value", which copies the current value of the cell to the target cell.

At home, I use LibreOffce.
Although I have tried to find a feature identical to "Paste Special > Value" in both LibreOffice and OpenOffice.org, I couldn't find it.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 29):

Just hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or `Paste Special...` from the `Edit` menu, unselect `Paste all`, and select `Text` or `Numbers`:

[image]