# libreoffice what is a fast way to paste special > text and numbers only (aka paste special values)?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

I copy and then paste values in excel quite a bit (when I use Excel). When I use LibreOffice  you can do the same thing (see [related question here](https://superuser.com/questions/372583)) but it is oh so tedious!

It gets especially tedious as I occasionally use the other options under paste special. Since this paste special values dialogue box remembers your last settings, to get the right past special I have to look at its current settings and check and uncheck until I get what I want. Since I frequently past just values I would much rather have a set of keystrokes my fingers could memorize and I could repeat each time I want to do this.

**How can I get a set of keystrokes that will consistently paste just the text and the numbers in libre office?** Since I want to be able to do this quickly I prefer fewer keystrokes to more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'll keep this answer here because it is more general than using a builtin command as suggested in [my other answer](https://superuser.com/a/593625/58777) — with a macro you can use any combination of paste options, not just a couple of predefined operations.)

You can define a macro and bind it to a key combination. The simplest way is probably to use the macro recorder:

1. Ensure that macro recording is turned on: Choose **Tools** → **Options**, choose the LibreOffice → General page, then check the “Enable macro recording” option.
2. Prepare to record the macro: Copy a cell to clipboard (options offered for the **Paste Special…** command depend on clipboard contents, so you need to have something coming from LibreOffice Calc in the clipboard if you want to record a macro for pasting data copied from Calc).
3. Select an empty cell to which you will paste the copied data.
4. Start macro recording: Choose **Tools** → **Macros** → **Record Macro**. The ”Record Macro” toolbar with a **Stop Recording** button will appear.
5. Select **Edit** → **Paste Special…**, then choose the combination of options you want to record in the macro and press **OK**.
6. Click the **Stop Recording** button; a dialog for saving the macro will appear. Enter the new macro name (e.g., `PasteAsTextOrNumber`), select `My Macros/Standard/Module1` in the left tree, then press the **Save** button. (If you enter a macro name which already exists in the module, you will need to confirm that you want to overwrite the old macro; there is no way to append new action to an existing macro using just the macro recorder.)
7. Now you can assign the macro to a shortcut key. Select **Tools** → **Customize**, then switch to the “Keyboard” tab, select the desired shortcut key combination in the top list, then find the macro in bottom lists:

   - Category: LibreOffice Macros → user → Standard → Module1
   - Function: your macro name (e.g., `PasteAsTextOrNumber`)

   Press **Modify** to assign the macro to the key combination.

   You can also create a toolbar button for the macro using the “Toolbars” tab.

The macro code generated for me when only “Text” and “Numbers” options were checked is:

```
sub PasteAsTextOrNumber
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(5) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "Flags"
args1(0).Value = "SV"
args1(1).Name = "FormulaCommand"
args1(1).Value = 0
args1(2).Name = "SkipEmptyCells"
args1(2).Value = false
args1(3).Name = "Transpose"
args1(3).Value = false
args1(4).Name = "AsLink"
args1(4).Value = false
args1(5).Name = "MoveMode"
args1(5).Value = 4

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertContents", "", 0, args1())


end sub
```

Answer (score 8):

After looking more closely at the “Customize” dialog, I found commands which probably do what you want without using macros:

1. Select **Tools** → **Customize**, then switch to the “Keyboard” tab.
2. Select the desired key combination in the “Shortcut Keys” list.
3. Select “Edit” in the “Category” list, then select `.uno:PasteOnlyValue` in the “Function” list. (According to [this bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58712), since LibreOffice 4.0.0 this item should be labeled as “Paste Only Value”, possibly translated to your language; I'm still using 3.6 here.)

   There are also several other related commands in the “Edit” category:

   - `.uno:PasteOnly` (Paste Only)
   - `.uno:PasteOnlyFormula` (Paste Only Formula)
   - `.uno:PasteOnlyText` (Paste Only Text)
4. Press the **Modify** button to assign the function to the key combination.

Answer (score 5):

I have been playing around with the Paste Special menu that gets brought up by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. I noticed that some keys toggle options. I can't seem to find any documentation though. Here are the hot keys docs for Libre office calc [General Shortcut Keys in LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Shortcut_Keys_in) I can't find anything through searching the site either.

So I guess I'll just go through and see what they do.

- a = Selects "Add" radio button.
- b = N/A
- c = Toggles selection of "OK" and "Cancel".
- d = Toggles "Date & time" check box.
- e = Selects "None" radio button.
- f = Toggles "Formulas" check box.
- g = N/A
- h = Opens help menu.
- i = Selects "Don't shift" radio button.
- j = N/A
- k = Toggles "Skip empty cells" check box.
- l = Toggles "Link" check box.
- m = Toggles "Formats" check box.
- n = Toggles "Numbers" check box.
- o = Selects "Objects" but does not toggle?
- p = Toggles "paste all" check box.
- q = N/A.
- r = Selects "Right" radio button.
- s = Selects "Subtract" radio button.
- t = Toggles "Transpose" check box.
- u = N/A
- v = Selects "Divide" radio button.
- w = Selects "Down" radio button.
- x = Toggles "Text" check box.
- y = Selects "Multiply" radio button.
- z = N/A

Nothing with punctuation or numbers. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+letter seem to have same effect as lowercase letter.